# Recycler View - Custom Checkbox: keeping state while scrolling

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, adapter

I've seen quite a few posts about this "issue" with RecyclerView, but I can't manage to fix it.

Every time I scroll, my custom CheckBoxes (starStyle) keep turning on/off.
I've tried to follow other solutions here on Stack, but none seems to do the job for me.

Just to explain the structure of my app, I've a long list (each item has a StarStyle CheckBox): when I click on an item, the app takes me in the Details Page for that item, where I can set the CheckBox, too. I managed to bind the list's checkbox and the one in the detail page, but I still having this annoying problem.

Here my code for the **ListFragment**:

```
public class PetrolStationListFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mPetrolStationRecyclerView;
    private PetrolStationAdapter mAdapter;

    private int itemPosition;
    private int mLastAdapterClickPosition = -1;
    private List<Boolean> mCheckState = new ArrayList<>();

    public static boolean toBeCreated;

    private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";


    // Design pattern to instantiate a new fragment.
    public static PetrolStationListFragment newInstance(int position) {
        PetrolStationListFragment fragment = new PetrolStationListFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);

        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }


    /********************************************************/

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_petrol_station_list, container, false);

        mPetrolStationRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.petrol_recycler_view);
        mPetrolStationRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        updateUI();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        updateUI();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        PetrolStationDAO petrolStationDAO = PetrolStationDAO.get(getActivity());
        List<PetrolStation> petrolStations = petrolStationDAO.getPetrolStations();

        if (mAdapter == null || toBeCreated) {
            mAdapter = new PetrolStationAdapter(petrolStations);
            mPetrolStationRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            toBeCreated = false;
        } else {
            if (mLastAdapterClickPosition < 0) {
                mAdapter.setPetrolStations(petrolStations);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(mLastAdapterClickPosition);
                mLastAdapterClickPosition = -1;
            }

            mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(itemPosition);
        }
    }

    private class PetrolStationHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private PetrolStation mPetrolStation;

        private TextView mNameTextView;
        private TextView mAddressTextView;
        private TextView mDistanceTextView;
        private CheckBox mCheckBox;
        private int mPosition;

        public PetrolStationHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            mNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station_name_text_view);
            mAddressTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station_address_text_view);
            mDistanceTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station_distance_text_view);
            mCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        }

        public void bindPetrolStation(PetrolStation petrolStation, int position) {
            mPetrolStation = petrolStation;
            mNameTextView.setText(mPetrolStation.getName());
            mAddressTextView.setText("Via Verdi, 19/A");
            mDistanceTextView.setText("300 meters");

            mPosition = position;
            //mCheckBox.setChecked(mPetrolStation.isFavourite());
            mCheckBox.setChecked(mCheckState.get(mPosition));
            Log.d("BIND_POSITION", "position: " + mPosition + " / status: " + mCheckState.get(mPosition));

            mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    boolean boxChecked = mPetrolStation.isFavourite();
                    Log.d("BOX_CHECKED_POSITION", "boxChecked: " + boxChecked);

                    if (boxChecked) {
                        mPetrolStation.setFavourite(false);
                    } else {
                        mPetrolStation.setFavourite(true);
                    }

                    if (boxChecked) {
                        mCheckState.set(mPosition, false);
                    } else {
                        mCheckState.set(mPosition, true);
                    }

                    Log.d("CHECK_POSITION", "mCheckState: " + mCheckState);

                    // TODO: DB connection.
//                    PetrolStationDAO.get(getActivity()).updateItem(mCrime);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            itemPosition = mPetrolStationRecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
            Intent intent = PetrolStationPagerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), mPetrolStation.getId());
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    private class PetrolStationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PetrolStationHolder> {

        private List<PetrolStation> mPetrolStations;

        public PetrolStationAdapter(List<PetrolStation> petrolStations) {
            mPetrolStations = petrolStations;

            for (int i = 0; i < mPetrolStations.size(); i++) {
                mCheckState.add(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public PetrolStationHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_petrol_station, parent, false);

            return new PetrolStationHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(PetrolStationHolder holder, int position) {
            PetrolStation petrolStation = mPetrolStations.get(position);
            holder.bindPetrolStation(petrolStation, position);
//            holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mPetrolStations.size();
        }

        public void setPetrolStations(List<PetrolStation> petrolStations) {
            mPetrolStations = petrolStations;
        }

    }

}
```

Here the one for the **DetailsFragment**:

```
public class PetrolStationFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PETROL_STATION_ID = "petrol_station_id";

    private PetrolStation mPetrolStation;
    private TextView mInfo;
    private CheckBox mCheckBox;

    private static TabLayout mTabLayout;
    private static ViewPager mViewPager;
    private static int intItems = 2;

    // Navigation Tab constants.
    private static final int SELF_SERVICE_POSITION = 0;
    private static final int FULL_SERVICE_POSITION = 1;


    // Design pattern to instantiate a new fragment.
    public static PetrolStationFragment newInstance(long petrolStationId) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putLong(ARG_PETROL_STATION_ID, petrolStationId);

        PetrolStationFragment fragment = new PetrolStationFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }


    /********************************************************/

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        long mId = getArguments().getLong(ARG_PETROL_STATION_ID);
        mPetrolStation = PetrolStationDAO.get(getActivity()).getPetrolStation(mId);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceStace) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_petrol_station, container, false);

        mInfo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.petrol_station);
        mCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        mInfo.setText(mPetrolStation.getName());
        mCheckBox.setChecked(mPetrolStation.isFavourite());

        // TODO: to fix.
        mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isFavourite) {
                mPetrolStation.setFavourite(isFavourite);
            }
        });

        // Setup Views.
        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.pager_header);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        // Set an Adapter for the View Pager.
        TabPagerAdapter tabPagerAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(tabPagerAdapter);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(SELF_SERVICE_POSITION);

        mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

            int flag;

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

        });

        mInfo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                mPetrolStation.setName(charSequence.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        // Return fragment with respect to position.
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment;

            switch (position) {

                case SELF_SERVICE_POSITION: {
                    fragment = SelfServiceFragment.newInstance();

                    return fragment;
                }

                case FULL_SERVICE_POSITION: {
                    fragment = FullServiceFragment.newInstance();

                    return fragment;
                }

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return intItems;
        }

        // This method returns the title of the tab according to its position.
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position) {

                case SELF_SERVICE_POSITION: {
                    String mSelfService = getResources().getString(R.string.self_service);

                    return mSelfService;
                }

                case FULL_SERVICE_POSITION: {
                    String mFullService = getResources().getString(R.string.full_service);

                    return mFullService;
                }

            }

            return null;

        }

    }

}
```

Any hints about how to solve this issue?
Am I missing some kind of check?

Comment: Try moving the setting of the isChecked to after you set the onCheckChangedListener.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but it's not working. I feel like I'm missing something, but I can't understand what. My code is almost identical to the ones I've seen in other Questions.

Comment: try something like this
holder._patientCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
holder._patientCheckbox.setChecked(deleted);
holder._patientCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

Answer (score 1):

Use a List of boolean type to hold the state of the checkbox. By default fill your collection with a false value.

When you select a checkbox change the state of the map using the set method

As you know When you scroll there will be a call to your adapter there you read the value from the map using get and set it to checkbox

```java
List < Boolean > checkstate = new ArrayList < Boolean > ();

// Inside the adapter constructor
for (i = 0; i < itemSize; i++) {
    checkstate.add(false);
}
```

Inside your Viewholder add below Line what it does is whatever the updated value of checkbox will set to your checkbox. Initially all the Items  will be false
`yourCheckbox.setChecked(checkstate.get(position));`

Now inside onCheckedChanged Listener

```java
if (boxchecked) {
    checkstate.set(position, true);
} else {
    checkstate.set(position, false);
}
```

Comment: I've read HashMaps don't support primitive types, like boolean. May I ask for a good guide on how to build one like you told me?

Comment: I've tried it, but it doesn't seem to work.
I've updated my question with your solution.